# Sqlitedatabase + unity

Tags: database, unity-game-engine

**i'm trying to connect my unity in sqlite database but i have an error. what does the error means ?**

```
IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.GetSQLiteType (Int32 i)
Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.VerifyType (Int32 i, DbType typ)
Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.GetString (Int32 i)
callOneUser.GetOneUsername () (at Assets/callOneUser.cs:41)
callOneUser.Start () (at Assets/callOneUser.cs:22)
```

**i'm trying to use this code. this is my void Start()**

```
void Start()
    {
       Connection = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/English_Booster_Game_DB.s3db"; //Path to database.
        GetOneUsername();
    }
```

**this is the GetOneUsername() process.**

```
public void GetOneUsername()
    {
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(Connection)) 
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            using (IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                string selectoneusername = "select UserData_name from user_data where UserData_status = 1";

                dbCmd.CommandText = selectoneusername;

                using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        name.text = reader.GetString(1);
                    }
                    dbConnection.Close();
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line is line 22? The error itself means you're trying to access an element index outside of the range of the array. For example, if you have an array with 2 elements, their indexes are `0` and `1` respectively. This error can be invoked by trying to access index `2` of that array -- because it's outside the range of that data structure. (It doesn't have to be an array, it's just an example and what this error is telling you).

Answer (score 1):

In your query string, you get one column `UserData_name`.

```
string selectoneusername = "select UserData_name from user_data where UserData_status = 1";
```

It only returns you a column and index in C# start from **"Zero"**. So you should change this line of your script:

```
name.text = reader.GetString(1);
```

to:

```
name.text = reader.GetString(0);
```

I hope it helps you